# how to scatter (or) plot group color matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, colors, scatter

I have the data matrix M size N by 3 where

M(:,1) and M(:,2) are the point represent in x,y axis and M(:,3) represent the group assign number

I try to use scatter plot that plot color differently according to the group assign

```
figure;
scatter(M(:,1) , M(:,2) , 3 ,?????? ,'fill');
```

I was confused to assign the group number into the color assignment by create another color representation group array C where C is matrix g by 3 ( g is a number of group and 3 represent color array element between 0-1)

I try ????? = `C(M(:,3),:)`  but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with  didn't work? Do you get an error?

The code you suggested works for me:

```
C = [1 0 0;
     0 1 0;
     0 0 1];

M = [rand(10,2)  round(2*rand(10,1))+1];

figure(1);
scatter(M(:,1) , M(:,2) , 3, C(M(:,3),:) ,'fill');
```

[image]

Is it possible that somethings wrong with your `C` or `M`?